# How to perform the Text Similarity using BERT on 10M+ corpus? Using LSH/ ANNOY/ fiass or sklearn?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, pytorch, bert-language-model, lsh

My idea is to extract the `CLS` token for all the text in the DB and save it in CSV or somewhere else. So when a new text comes in, instead of using the `Cosine Similarity/JAccard/MAnhattan/Euclidean` or other distances, I have to use some approximation like `LSH, ANN (ANNOY, sklearn.neighbor)` or the one given here `faiss` . How can that be done? I have my code as:

**PyTorch**:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, I am a text")).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
```

**Using Tensorflow:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute"))[None, :]  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
```

and I  think can get the `CLS` token as: (**Please correct if wrong**)

```
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]
cls_embedding = last_hidden_states[0][0]
```

Please tell me if it's the right way to use and how can I use any of the `LSH, ANNOT, faiss` or something like that?

So for every text, there'll a `768` length vector and we can create a **N(No of texts 10M)x768** matrix, how can I find the **Index**  of `top-5` data points (texts) which are most similar to the given **image/embedding/data point**?